# What's a good hash algorithm for hashing a short length (e.g. 256 bytes) buffer, which must be fast and very collision resistant?

Tags: hash

It doesn't need to be cryptographically secure.

1. Would CRC64 be a good choice?
2. What's the minimum hash length that can be considered cryptographically secure these days?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're only doing cryptography secure here.

Comment: If you need it to be fully collision resistant you may still need a cryptographically secure hash though, so that's at odds with what you're asking. With regards to the minimum hash length, I'd guess that 112 bits security is still OK, which you could get with either SHA-2-224 or the SHA-3 variant of the same.

Comment: Perhaps you should spell out what you mean by 'collision resistant'; do you mean a) two random messsages are very unlikely to have the same hash, or b) it is extremely difficult to find two different messages with the same hash (even given the details of the algorithm).  CRC64 is decent against meaning (a); it doesn't meet meaning (b) even slightly...

Answer (score 3):

First you should check if a cryptographically secure hash such as SHA-2 is fast enough. It is likely it is fast enough, and then the fine details of your weakened collision resistance requirement become irrelevant. 
If you really need something fast you may consider CRC-64, but it is obviously not cryptographically secure, It is rather trivial to construct collisions for CRC-64. However if you are trying to protect against random collisions, it may suffice, and with random input data, you may assume CRC-64 won't collide much more then a random function which mean you can use birthday paradox to calculate the chance of having a collision. Essentially you need number_of_messages << 2^(bit_length/2)